# Libreoffice Impress Export as Images extension does not work

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-impress

**Libreoffice Impress *Export as Images*** extension does not work. "Export as Images" Menu is not being added to File Menu.

Link- http://extensions-test.libreoffice.org/extension-center/export-as-images

I am using **Libreoffice 3.4**. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround: start the `Export as Images` macro *manually*. It's located under `My Macros` -> `ExportImages` -> `ExportImages`. Look for a macro named `ExportAsImages` and run it. Once found and started, it works fine :) (i don't know why it doesn't show up in the File menu).

EDIT:

Editing the macro is possible using the built-in IDE: once it's installed, you can access its LibreOffice Basic source using `Tools`-> `Macros` -> `Organize Macros...` -> `LibreOffice Basic`.

It's also possible to **run it from the command line**, **but** in its current form, it requires user interaction to specify the output file name and graphics format. So i assume it isn't possible to run it completely in "headless" mode without modifying the source. To run it from the command line on Linux, converting the file `/tmp/mypresentation.odp`, use:

```
$ simpress /tmp/mypresentation.odp "vnd.sun.star.script:ExportImages.ExportImages.ExportAsImages?language=Basic&location=application"
```

Comment: thanks tohuwawohu. 
[1] Is there any way to **edit this macro**?
[2] Can the macro be **run from the command line** that takes the odp file as input?

Comment: @Van den Graff: i've edited my reply to cover those additional points.